# Can light pollution cause cancer?

Tags: pathophysiology, human-physiology

[Impaired circadian rhythm is associated with cancer.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306987710001222) Light pollution affects the circadian rhythm and the circadian rhythm affects the metabolism. But what is the (molecular) connection between impaired circadian rhythm altered metabolism and cancer?

Comment: Do you have a link to the full text of the linked paper? It is not open access. Additionally, just from reading the abstract, the authors are proposing a hypothesis, and haven't actually tested anything. Correlation is not causation. Using Google Scholar, I couldn't find any actual research studies that cited this article testing this hypothesis.

Comment: @MattDMo It is not that hard: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150529/795452382N_vtelen_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png I don't have full text either by most of the articles. Only libraries and universities use to buy access only, it is too expensive. So if you are member of a library then you can probably read the full text at least by some of the online journals.

Comment: @MattDMo Another relevant articles I have found: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13277-012-0611-0  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030438351300709X http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.3109/07420528.2013.782315 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016648013001731 http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24729125 http://www.pnas.org/content/108/46/18790.full